# Manifolds with $[,]:H^1(X,T_X)\times H^1(X,T_X)\rightarrow 0$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, deformation-theory, kahler-manifolds

Let $X$ be a compact complex manifold, for arbitrary $\phi_1,\phi_2\in H^1(X,T_X)$, if the Lie bracket $[,]:H^1(X,T_X)\times H^1(X,T_X)\rightarrow H^2(X,T_X)$ always maps $\phi_1,\phi_2$ to zero, i.e.$[\phi_1,\phi_2]=0\in H^2(X,T_X)$, then $X$ admits an unobstructed deformation?

As we know, if we assume $H^2(X,T_X)=0$, then of course the Lie bracket gives a map $[,]:H^1(X,T_X)\times H^1(X,T_X)\rightarrow 0$, and for a Calabi-Yau manifold, by Tian-Todorov lemma and $\partial \bar\partial$-lemma, the Lie bracket also maps $H^1(X,T_X)\times H^1(X,T_X)$ to $0$, so, generally, if we assume that the Lie bracket always maps $H^1(X,T_X)\times H^1(X,T_X)$ to $0$, then can we say $X$ must have an unobstructed deformation?

Comment: No, this just tells you that there is no first order obstruction to deform $X$. If you can read french, I recommend [this seminar lecture](http://www.numdam.org/item/SHC_1960-1961__13_1_A3_0/) by Douady, in particular the counter-example at the end.

Comment: @abx, I think I have made a stupid mistake, for $\phi=\phi_1 t+\phi_2 t^2+\phi_3 t^3+...$, I wrongly think all the $\phi_i \in H^1(X,T_X)$, but actually, except for $i=1$, $\phi_i$ only in $\Gamma(X,A^{0,1}(T_X))$.